# Isn't there an "auto disposition" method?

Tags: jgraphx, jgraph, mxgraph

I have a graph with nodes and edges and I want to display them.
Isn't there any function which, given this graph, displays it without me to give exact coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can use the auto layout
http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/layout/mxCompactTreeLayout-js.html
this url construct a compact tree layout.

```
var layoutMgr = new mxLayoutManager(graph);
    layoutMgr.getLayout = function(cell) {
    return layout;
};
```